# Blocks in sequences from {1,...,k}

Tags: sequences-and-series

In [Lecture Notes on Enormous integers](http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman.8/pdf/EnormousInt112201.pdf) Harvey M. Friedman introduces

"*... longest finite sequence $x_1,...,x_n$ from $\{1,...,k\}$ such that for
no i < j <= n/2 is $x_i,...,x_{2i}$ a subsequence of $x_j,...,x_{2j}$.
For k ≥ 1, let n(k) be the length of this longest finite
sequence.*"

Then, the author evaluates this function

"*Paul Sally runs a program for gifted high school students at
the University of Chicago.
He asked them to find n(1), n(2), n(3).
They all got n(1) = 3. One got n(2) = 11. Nobody reported
much on n(3).*"

which I fail to confirm. Consider 12 character word

```
001011111101
```

neither of its starting subsequences

```
00
 010
  1011
```

is contained in "doubled" subsequences and suggest n(2) = 13. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hmm... I recall proving that $n(2)=11$ for Dr. Sally earlier this year. Let me see if I can dig up the proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$00$ is a subsequence of $010$.  You seem to be thinking of substring/subword.